# Flutter app with a web view deployed to the web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Seems like it should be something simple. I'm converting a mobile app to have web support. There are a few pages within the app that use WebView to display things such as terms and conditions and FAQ's.

As the WebView widget only supports ios and android from what I can tell, how should I do this? Of all the platforms you'd think the web was the easiest to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, just after posting I came across `IFrameElement` which looking at this link https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-and-iframe-f26399aa1e2a should make it possible.

Comment: Does WebView work in web deployment now? Is IFrameElement necessary? How does it work?